# setInterval in React component gets duplicated when useState value changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing an array to a component. Every second I want to `console.log` the next item in the array.

In the code below every second the number of console logs doubles:

```
const Component = ({ someArray }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(0);

  setInterval(() => {
      setPosition(position + 1);
      console.log(someArray[position]);
  }, 1000);
```

I assume this is because the the component re-renders when the `position` state changes but I'm not sure what the solution is.

Comment: I'm not really au fait with these React hooks, but essentially you want the thing analogous to componentDidMount right? Which seems to be 'useEffect' https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using react hooks, you need use combination of useRef and useEffect - where you can compare prevProps with currentProps and clearInterval when needed.

```js
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

const Component = ({ someArray }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(0);
  const prevArray = usePrevious({ someArray });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setPosition(prevPosition => prevPosition + 1);
    }, 1000);
    if (prevArray && someArray && prevArray.someArray !== someArray || !someArray[position]) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  });
  
  return (
    <div>Position: {position}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component someArray={['1', '2', '3', '4']} />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Let me know if this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to prevent the repeated setInterval calls (rightly called on each render, as you say) :

```
let clearInterval;
const Component = ({ someArray }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(0);

  if (!clearInterval) {
    clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setPosition(position + 1);
      console.log(someArray[position]);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Ok - it seems you can't call setPosition like that.
It's much easier if you use a standard Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { position: 0 };
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ position: this.state.position + 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => {}}>{this.state.position}</button>;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/q3pzw3623q

Comment: This fixed the duplicate timer issue but position isn't being incremented.

Answer (score 0):

To me judging from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html looks like you want to do like so

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        setPosition(position + 1);
        console.log(someArray[position]);
    }, 1000);
}, []);
```

Comment: This doesn't increment position

Comment: useEffect is called like componentDidUpdate (according to the docs), so I don't think it will fix the multiple calls to setInterval

Comment: @jsdeveloper that much is at least fine, as the last argument (this []) is essentially the componentDidUpdate bit, it apparently means to only call the useEffect if something inside the array updates. Not sure I understand why it's not incrementing position

Comment: @Evanss Seems to be a reasonably well known 'problem' https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ provides a solution. Makes sense as to why what I proposed didn't work

Answer (score 0):

As Countingstuff pointed out there is an extensive blog post on this by on of the React core team:
https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Create a useInterval hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Then useInterval can replace setInterval:

```
const Component = ({ someArray }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = React.useState(0);

  setInterval(() => {
      useInterval(position + 1);
      console.log(someArray[position]);
  }, 1000);
```